# How can I specify the data value of an item in a /testfor command?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have used the `/testfor` command a lot but I ran into a problem I thought you could help with.

This is my command:

```
/testfor @p[r=3] {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:log",Count:64b}]}
```

In this command I want it to test for log number 2, which is *birch* wood, but the thing is I don't know how to insert that.

I want it so it detects if the player has a 64 stack of birch wood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Damage` tag holds the metadata value. It has a datatype of "short", so you append the value with an "s":

```
/testfor @p[r=3] {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:log",Damage:2s,Count:64b}]}
```